# Pipe limit data in bytes

Tags: pipe, dd, cloning

I'm trying to do an 'advanced case' of cloning.

There is a pipe writing to a block device, at the end of which there is a partition that should not be touched. I know where this partition starts. In this case I want to override the partition table.

For the sake of simpilicty the pipe starts with `dd if=myfile`.

```
dd if=myfile > /dev/sda
```

I could do something like

```
dd if=myfile | dd bs=1B count=startofmypartition-~1000000 > /dev/sda
```

But are there any better ways to do that and are there any drawbacks to this method?

`pv` has a size option, but it states that it is only used to calcualte the ETA, so I'm not sure if this will work:
(from the manpage:)

```
-s SIZE, --size SIZE Assume the total amount of data to be transferred is SIZE bytes when calculating percentages and ETAs. The same suffixes of "k", "m" etc can be used as with -L.
```

I know that there will be more write operations, but it should turn out to be the same data on the disk using the same amount space - as long it's not a tape drive.

Comment: -S in addition to -s makes pv stop at the specified size

Comment: Sorry; it seems that I was using an old manual: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dd bs=1` is very inefficient as it does one `read()` and one `write()` system call per byte. It doesn't make much sense to use `dd` anyway on a block device (unless you want to use special flags like `conv=noerror,sync...` to handle errors or offsets)

Here you could do:

```
offset=$(($(cat /sys/class/block/sda3/start) * 512)) &&
 pv -trabSs "$offset" < myfile > /dev/sda
```

(or use `head -c "$offset"` if you don't care about the progress information).

`pv` and `head` will choose adequate buffer size to optimise performance.

(note that since you're writing data at the start of the disk, you're going to effectively overwrite the partition table!).

Another  alternative could be to create a new block device that maps only the sections of `/dev/sda`  that you're willing to overwrite

Like:

```
echo "0 $(cat /sys/class/block/sda3/start) linear /dev/sda 0" |
  dmsetup create writable_sda &&
cp myfile /dev/mapper/writable_sda
```

Comment: Why do you multiply `* 512` if the -S option is in bytes and the output of `/start` is in bytes?

Comment: @rudib, the content of `/start` is in 512-byte units, not bytes.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was making wrong assumptions; sorry I was comparing to fdisk which uses 512-byte units and I thought it were bytes...